# JavaFx: Label text width

Tags: java, javafx, label, javafx-8

I have a problem with the `Label`'s width. If I change the size of the window and the label's width doesn't fit to the window.

I expect something like:

Initial: 012345678901234567890123456789

After resize: 01234567890123...

But the actual state:

[image: Initial state]

After resize:

[image: After resize]

How can I get my expected result?

Here is the `.fxml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="stackoverflow.labeltest.Controller">
    <HBox>
        <Label fx:id="label"/>
    </HBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: The `HBox` is probably still the same size, as `AnchorPane` doesn't resize its children (I think). Try removing the `AnchorPane`, having the `HBox` as the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `AnchorPane` does not resize a child without constraints. You need to set the `rightAnchor` and `leftAnchor` constraints of the `HBox`. (You could also simply use the `HBox` as root.)

```xml
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
            xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
            fx:controller="stackoverflow.labeltest.Controller">
    <children>
        <HBox AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="label"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: Yes you are right I am using simply the `HBox` as root and it works :) Thanks.